# Using rdmsr/rdpmc for branch prediction accuracy

Tags: c, x86, performancecounter, branch-prediction, papi

I am trying to understand how does a branch prediction unit work in a CPU.

I have used `papi` and also linux's `perf-events` but both of them do not give accurate results (for my case).

This is my code:

```
void func(int* arr, int sequence_len){
  for(int i = 0; i < sequence_len; i++){
      // region starts
      if(arr[i]){
          do_sth();
      }
      // region ends
  }
}
```

My array consists of 0's and 1's. It has a pattern with a size of `sequence_len`. For example, if my size is 8, then it has a pattern of `0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1` or something like that.

**Trial 1:**

I am trying to understand how CPU predicts those branches. So, I have used papi and set up performance counter for branch predictions mispredicted (I know that it also counts indirect branches).

```
int func(){
  papi_read(r1);
  for(){
    //... same as above
  }
  papi_read(r2);
  return r2-r1;
}

int main(){
   init_papi();
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     res[i] = func();

   print(res[i]);
}
```

What I see as an output is that (for sequence length of 200)

```sh
100 #iter1
40  #iter2
10  #iter3
3
0
0
#...
```

So, at first, the CPU blindly predicts the sequence, only success half of the time. In the next iterations, the CPU can predict better and better. After some amount of iterations, the CPU can guess that perfectly.

**Trial 2**

I would like to see, at which array index does the CPU misprediction.

```
int* func(){
  int* results;
  for(){
    papi_read(r1);
    if(arr[i])
        do_sth();   
    papi_read(r2);
    res[i] = r2-r1;
  }
  return res;
}

int main(){
   init_papi();
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     res[i] = func();

   print(res[i]);
}
```

Expected result:

```sh
#1st iteration, 0 means no mispred, 1 means mispred
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0... # total of 200 results
Mispred: 100/200
#2nd iteration
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0... # total of 200 results
Mispred: 40/200 # it learned from previous iteration
#3rd iteration
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0... # total of 200 results
Mispred: 10/200 # continues to learn
#...
```

Received result:

```sh
#1st iteration
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0... # total of 200 results
Mispred: 100/200
#2nd iteration
1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0... # total of 200 results
Mispred: 100/200 # it DID NOT learn from previous iteration
#3rd iteration
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0... # total of 200 results
Mispred: 100/200 # NO LEARNING
#...
```

**My observation**

When I measure the misprediction outside of the for loop, I can see that CPU learns from its mispredictions. However, when I try to measure single branch instructions misprediction, then the CPU either cannot learn, or I am measuring it wrongly.

**My explanation**

I am giving 200 as a sequence length. The CPU has one small branch predictor, like 2-3 bit saturated counter in Intels, and one big global branch predictor. When I measure outside of the loop, I introduce less noise to the measurement. By less noise, I mean the `papi` calls.

Think about this: outside of the loop measurement

global history is: `papi_start, branch_outcome1, branch_outcome2, branch_outcome3, ..., papi_end, papi_start (2nd loop of main iteration), branch_outcome1, ...`

So, the branch predictor somehow finds the pattern in the same branch.

However, if I try to measure single branch instruction then the global history is:
`papi_start, branchoutcome1, papiend, papistart, branchoutcome2, papiend...`

So, I am introducing more and more branches to global history. I assume the global history cannot hold many branch entries and therefore, it cannot find any correlation/pattern in the desired if statement(branch).

**As a result**

I need to measure a single branch prediction outcome. I know that the CPU can learn the 200 pattern if I don't introduce papi too much. I have looked at the papi calls and I have seen lots of for loops, if conditions.

That is why I need better measurement. I have tried linux `perf-event` but it makes `ioctl` calls, which is a system call and I pollute the global history with system calls, and therefore, not a good measurement.

I have read that `rdpmc` and `rdmsr` instructions and I assume that since they are only instructions, I will not pollute the global history, and I can measure single branch instruction at a time.

However, I have no clue about how I can do that. I have AMD 3600 CPU. These are the links that I found online but I couldn't figure out how to do that. In addition to that, am I missing something?

[Intel rdpmc](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/595214)

[AMD Performance manual](https://www.amd.com/system/files/TechDocs/56255_OSRR.pdf)

Comment: Why not trying on a bare metal software ? on an ARM microcontroller for instance. the behavior would be more predictable and easier to debug since there is no OS ?

Comment: there is a nice article speaking about measuring branch prediction on ARM cortex here : https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/measuring-the-impact-of-branch-prediction-for-cortex-r7-and-cortex-r8

Comment: Well, I want to measure the AMD processor.  I think your link does not provide a valuable answer to my question. But I'll look into that just to learn new things. @The_Average_Engineer

Comment: @The_Average_Engineer: x86 CPUs boot up in real mode, and there's always firmware built-in to the motherboard which either loads a UEFI application or a legacy BIOS boot sector.  It's not like an ARM board where you're basically writing the firmware into flash.  I don't think bare metal (or even running under UEFI) is a very useful suggestion.  At least a UEFI application wouldn't have to do a bunch of osdev crap (like setting up a GDT and page tables) just to run normal 64-bit code, and could use UEFI functions to save results to a file.  But you wouldn't have a debugger or anything.

Answer (score 6):

You have assumed that the PAPI and/or perf_events code has a relatively light footprint.  This is incorrect.  If you change the performance counter event to something like "instructions retired" or "CPU cycles not halted", you will be able to see how much overhead this operation contains in your software environment.  The details will depend on your OS version, but I expect the overhead to be in the hundreds of instructions/thousands of cycles because of the kernel crossing required to read the counters in perf_events (which is used by PAPI).  The code path will certainly include its own branches.

If your kernel supports "User-Mode RDPMC" (CR4.PCE=1), you can read a performance counter with a single instruction.  Examples are available in https://github.com/jdmccalpin/low-overhead-timers.

Even when limiting the measurement code to the native RDPMC instruction (and the surrounding code to save the results), measurements are disruptive to the processor pipeline.  RDPMC is a microcoded instruction.  On the Ryzen core, the instruction executes 20 micro-ops and has a throughput of one instruction per 20 cycles. (Ref: https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf)

Any measurements at fine granularities are challenging because the out-of-order capabilities of modern processors interact with the user code in ways that are poorly documented and difficult to anticipate.  More notes on this topic (also relevant to AMD processors) are at http://sites.utexas.edu/jdm4372/2018/07/23/comments-on-timing-short-code-sections-on-intel-processors/

Comment: Further information on how to perform low-overhead performance measurements can also be found in the following paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.03282

Answer (score 5):

The `perf_event_open()` [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) describes how to correctly use `rdpmc` with events created via that interface. The approach described in @JohnDMcCalpin's answer also works, but it's based on programming the event control registers directly. Given a set of hardware events, figuring out how to schedule these events on the available hardware performance counters can be difficult. The `perf_event` subsystem handles this problem for you, which is a major advantage.

The `perf_event` subsystem supports `rdpmc` since Linux 3.4.

Starting with `<linux/perf_event.h>`, the following works:

1. do `perf_event_open()` to prepare to read counter of `type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE` `config = PERF_COUNT_HW_BRANCH_MISSES`

   ```
   struct perf_event_attr attr ;
   int fd ;

   memset(&attr, 0, sizeof(attr)) ;

   attr.type   = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE ;
   attr.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_BRANCH_MISSES;
   attr.size = sizeof(attr) ;        // for completeness
   attr.exclude_kernel = 1 ;         // count user-land events

   perf_fd = (int)sys_perf_event_open(&attr, 0, -1, -1, PERF_FLAG_FD_CLOEXEC) ;
                                     // this pid, any cpu, no group_fd
   ```

   where:

   ```
   static long
   sys_perf_event_open(struct perf_event_attr* attr,
                                 pid_t pid, int cpu, int group_fd, ulong flags)
   {
     return syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, attr, pid, cpu, group_fd, flags) ;
   }
   ```
2. associate the perf_fd with a mmap page:

   ```
   struct perf_event_mmap_page* perf_mm ;

   perf_mm = mmap(NULL, page_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, perf_fd, 0) ;
   ```

   page_size can be 4096 for example. This buffer is used for storing samples. See the "Overflow handling" section of the documentation.
3. to read the counter need to combine some information in the `perf_mm` with what you read using `RDPMC` instruction, thus:

   ```
   uint64_t  offset, count ;
   uint32_t  lock, check, a, d, idx ;

   lock = perf_mm->lock ;
   do
     {
       check = lock ;
       __asm__ volatile("":::"memory") ;
       idx = perf_mm->index - 1 ;
       // Check that you're allowed to execute rdpmc. You can do this check once.
       // Check also that the event is currently active.
       // Starting with Linux 3.12, use cap_user_rdpmc.
       if (perf_mm->cap_user_rdpmc && idx) {
          // cap_user_rdpmc cannot change at this point because no code
          // that executes here that changes it. So it's safe.
          __asm__ volatile("\t rdpmc\n" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d) : "c" (idx)) ;
       }
       // In case of signed event counts, you have to use also pmc_width.
       // See the docs.
        offset = perf_mm->offset ;
       __asm__ volatile("":::"memory") ;
       lock = perf_mm->lock ;
     }
   while (lock != check) ;

   count = ((uint64_t)d << 32) + a ;
   if (perf_mm->pmc_width != 64)
     {
       // need to sign extend the perf_mm->pmc_width bits of count.
     } ;
   count += offset ;
   ```

   If the thread is not interrupted between the "start" and "end" reads, then I think we can assume that the `perf_mm` stuff will not change.  But if it is interrupted, then the kernel can update `perf_mm` stuff to account for any changes that affect this timing.
4. Note: The overhead around the `RDPMC` instructions is not huge, but I am experimenting with stripping all this back and seeing whether I can use the `RDPMC` results directly, provided that `perf_mm->lock` does not change.

Comment: There is a `__rdpmc` intrinsic, but apparently it was buggy until gcc6.5 / 7.4 / 8.3 ; [before that it wasn't properly volatile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54638486/counting-l1-cache-misses-with-papi-read-counters-gives-unexpected-results#comment96082521_54638486).  If you have newer GCC you can use it; but I guess inline asm is fine.  You left out C vars for the output of `rdpmc`.  Normally you want `"=a"(low_half_result)` or something.  It's a syntax error to omit the `(var_name)` part.

Comment: Thanks.  Fixed to `"=a" (a), "=d" (d)`.

Comment: @Hadi: thanks for the edits.  Is it necessary to check `if (pc->cap_user_rdpmc && idx)` in the read loop ?  I mentioned `time_offset` etc because the code sample in the documentation to show how to use `rdpmc` uses it, but it's not necessary to do so for these purposes.  You changed the `page_size` to say "4096 for example": do you mean it can be 4096 for this purpose -- namely, reading PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE counters using `rdpmc` ?  You also pointed at "Overflow handling" in the "documentation": how is that relevant in this case ?  Finally: how do I tell when I have a "signed event count" ?

Comment: @ChrisHall `idx` is invalid if the event is not currently active (e.g., due to multiplexing). If you try to `rdpmc` from a invalid `idx`, you'll either read the counter of a different event or an exception will occur. It may be sufficient to check for `cap_user_rdpmc` only once at the beginning of the program if you know for sure that no one else will may disable user-mode `rdpmc` later for some reason. That buffer is used for holding event samples. When the buffer gets fall, the kernel invokes  function you registered to process the buffer. The documentation discusses how the buffer is used.

Comment: @HadiBrais: I have failed to discover whether the hardware configuration of counters is per thread, per process or system wide.  If per thread/process, then I guess I can assume that `idx` will change only if/when I call `open_perf_event()` ?  I see `cap_user_rdpmc` can be changed from outside the process, but I don't care if a timing test then fails -- I care about the timing overhead !  The "documentation" (or FM) says "Overflows are generated only for sampling events"... I think I am configuring "counter events", so only require 1 page for the metadata because no ring buffer is required ?

Comment: @ChrisHall They're per thread, but a single thread can schedule more hardware events than there are hardware counters, which triggers multiplexing. That's how some events can be enabled but not active. Sure, you can remove the `cap_user_rdpmc` if you can guarantee that user-mode `rdpmc` is enabled at the time it's executed. Otherwise, the code will crash.